# How to set different password requirements with Formik and Yup depending on locale?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I'm dealing with a site where i have different password requirements depending on country, can anyone help me solve this please? This is how far I've come so far, but it still only requires 6 characters and nothing else.

```
        password: Yup.string()
            .when({
                is: locale => locale === 'mt',
                then: Yup.string().matches(
                    /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/,
                    'Must Contain 8 Characters, One Uppercase, One Lowercase, One Number and one special case Character'
                ),
                otherwise: Yup.string().min(6, 'Must containt at least 6 characters')
            })
            .required(intl.formatMessage({ id: 'inputs.password.required' }))
    });
```

locale is the country and is set in the url. It fetches locale correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use something like that:

```js
password: locale === 'mt' ? 
Yup.string().matches(/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$/,
                    'Must Contain 8 Characters, One Uppercase, One Lowercase, One Number and one special case Character'
                ) : Yup.string().min(6, 'Must containt at least 6 characters')
```

Comment: Yes! Of course! Worked like a charm! Thank you!